# OPA Rego issues counting

Tags: go, opa, open-policy-agent, rego

I am trying to write a rule but am running into an issue. I managed to extract the following from as my input:

```
myData:= [{"Key": "use", "Value": "1"}, {"Key": "use", "Value": "2"}, {"Key": "att1", "Value": "3"}]
```

I am trying to count the amount of times a key with the value use appears. However when I do:

```
p := {keep| keep:= myData[_]; myData.Key == "use"}
```

I assumed this would create a listing of all I would like to keep but the playground errors with:

```
1 error occurred: policy.rego:24: rego_type_error: undefined ref: data.play.myData.Key
    data.play.myData.Key
```

I hoped I could list them in `p` and then do `count(p) > 1` to check if more that one is listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your set comprehension for `p`, you're iterating over the objects in `myData`, assigning each element to `keep`. Then, you assert something on `myData.Key`. I think what you're looking for is

```
p := {keep| keep := myData[_]; keep.Key == "use"}
```

Be aware that it's a *set* comprehension, so `p` would be the same for these two inputs:

```
myData:= [{"Key": "use", "Value": "1"}]
myData:= [{"Key": "use", "Value": "1"}, {"Key": "use", "Value": "1"}]
```

You could use an array comprehension (`p := [ keep | keep := ... ]`) if that's not what you want.